# load animationImage from a table view Controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I use a UITableViewController to display a list of items, and one of the items selection must lead to a
 photo gallery created with animationImages. I usually declare the controllers associated to 
the first level selection with something like :

`MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];`

myController.title = @"title 1";

myController.rowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myControllerIcon.png"];

..

But I believe a UIViewController is needed to use animationImages.. 
How can I display a image animation directly from a table view ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have you image sequence build in this manner:

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage4.gif"],
nil];

UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];
[myAnimatedView initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25; // seconds
myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
[self addSubview:myAnimatedView];
[myAnimatedView release];
```

[Snatched from here](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/)

Then you can build your own cell or add the animationImage to the cell by adding it to either:

```
[cell setImage:myAnimatedView];
[cell setBackgroundView:myAnimatedView];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:myAnimatedView]
```

Comment: Hi,
When I try to create the image like this example, I obtain a warning "myController may not respond to '-addSubview', and it crashes when I select the navigation list item corresponding to myController.. 

I guess I should be using a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController right ? 
But if I do so, I can't use it anymore in my navigation list to display a corresponding item (as it has not been created as UITableViewStylePlain I can't use myController.rowImage=[..]).

Comment: Hi ackoverflow.
A viewController is a "View" and "Controller" in one. Something that can help you out a lot is to read up on what Apple has to say on the "Model-View-Controller" pattern which is the backbone of iPhone apps. Anyways, the controller has a view. So instead of UIViewController addSubView, you need UIViewController.view addSubView.